# Teradata parser messes up the query

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an update query in a stored procedure as below

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET column = v_col,
column1 = v_col2, 
..
..
WHERE seq_num = v_seq_num
```

There is an input variable to the stored procedure seq_num matching column name of the table. During run time the code becomes

```
UPDATE tablename FROM tablename
SET column = :var1,
column1 = :var2, 
..
..
WHERE :var12 = :var13
```

It assumes seq_num in the where clause as a variable and the query gives spool space error, because it updates tablename from tablename. Currently i cannot change the input variable name as it requires lots of code change. Is there a work around for this? Does anyone know what is happening here?
i was thinking about writing WHERE tablename.seq_num = v_seq_num.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the actual Update and table DDL? `WHERE tablename.seq_num` should work.

Comment: The below is the actual update...
UPDATE tablename 
SET column = v_col,
column1 = v_col2, 
..
..
WHERE seq_num = v_seq_num

seq_num is a BIGINT and there is a input parameter to the stored procedure with the same name seq_num as BIGINT.